What is the meaning of the second line of the piecewise output of SeriesCoefficient[]?
When I ask SeriesCoefficient[] to give me a general term, it outputs a response with head "Piecewise" that contains the general term in the first line and (every time I tried it) "0 True" in the second line. SeriesCoefficient[][[2]] brings back the '0' but not 'True'.  There is no [[3]].
My hunch is that this device is used for many functions (answering, say, "Is there valid output at input '0'?) but tbh I have no idea.  Thanks, TB
Example (from documentation):
SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-x], {x, 0, n}]

Output:


Are you asking what the second entry in piecewise means? It means for any other n, the result is zero. i.e. for n<0 the result is zero. True means for everything else. So in this case, everything else is  n<0.  To find the internal structure and levels of piecewise result, you can look at its FullForm.

In general, a series can start or end with any term. The Piecewise covers all possibilities. Look at f[x_] = Exp[-x]; Sum[SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}] x^n, {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] == f[x]

Second argument stands for default value of the Piecewise function when none of the conditions holds. Such a behavior of SeriesCoefficient[...] might be helpful, e.g., for the successive summation
Sum[SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-x], {x, 0, n}], {n, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] (*=>1/E*)

Still, this output of SeriesCoefficient[...] is a bit silly as the Piecewise evaluates to non-zero value even when n is non-integer positive. E.g. try
Sum[SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-x], {x, 0, n}] /. n -> k + 1/2, {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

If you want to avoid Piecewise, you can use
SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-x], {x, 0, n}, Assumptions->n>0] (*=> (-1)^n/n!*)


Thank you!  I will explore these.  TB
